# Unable to get N distinct records in SQL subquery

Tags: sql, distinct

I am trying to get only 2 occurrences for every `AgentName` in the below SQL query:-

```
SELECT j1.AgentName,
         j1.LatencyCount,
         j2.callid,
         j2.jittermax,
         j2.agentid
FROM 
    (SELECT agentname AS AgentName,
         count(agentid) AS LatencyCount
    FROM metals.client_logs_quality_monitor
    WHERE partition_0 >= '2019-09-23'
            AND CallTime > 1569222000
            AND CallTime <= 1569250399
    GROUP BY  agentname
    ORDER BY  LatencyCount DESC LIMIT 5 ) j1,metals.client_logs_quality_monitor j2
WHERE partition_0 >= '2019-09-23'
        AND j2.CallTime > 1569222000
        AND j2.CallTime <= 1569250399
        AND j1.AgentName = j2.agentname
ORDER BY  j1.AgentName DESC, jittermax DESC
```

Currently, I am getting below output:-

[image]

But I want it like below(Only 2 records per agent):-
[image]

I am not able to find any way to do that. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Also, let me know if you can suggest any modifications to the existing query because I want it to scan least no of records.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Actually, I am not having any database. I am running this query from AWS Athena on AWS S3 bucket files.

Comment: I just checked - Athena uses Apache Hive to define tables and create databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT j1.AgentName, j1.LatencyCount,
       j2.callid, j2.jittermax, j2.agentid
FROM (SELECT agentname AS AgentName,
             count(agentid) AS LatencyCount
      FROM metals.client_logs_quality_monitor
      WHERE partition_0 >= '2019-09-23' AND
            CallTime > 1569222000 AND
            CallTime <= 1569250399
      GROUP BY agentname
      ORDER BY LatencyCount DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) j1 JOIN
     (SELECT j2.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AgentName ORDER BY callid) as seqnum
      FROM metals.client_logs_quality_monitor j2
     ) j2
     ON j1.AgentName = j2.agentname
WHERE partition_0 >= '2019-09-23' AND
      j2.CallTime > 1569222000 AND
      j2.CallTime <= 1569250399 AND
      seqnum <= 2 
ORDER BY  j1.AgentName DESC, jittermax DESC;
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error in this query - SYNTAX_ERROR: line 16:13: Table 'clqm' not found

Comment: @Vyron Thanks for the edit. Now the query works fine.